# Why does changing the flux induces a voltage and thus a current

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

I have seen similiar Questions being asked for example [Why Does Change of Magnetic Flux Induce an emf?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114536/why-does-change-of-magnetic-flux-induce-an-emf)

However i am not satisfied with the answers.

It seems to me that this Question is usually answered with the equations or the pure Maths that this is a Vector identity.

However what is the visual view of this? in other words, what happens to the elctrons when we move some
cable thru a magnet. why does a voltage appear ? this surely means that in the space the charges are being seperated (to create difference of potential thus Voltage thus Current)

But how this exactly take place?

Also why does this not appear in stationary case?

While inserting the cable and while removing it the voltage has opposite charges.

Could someone explain this with the perspective of the electrons and what happens to them?

Thanks

Comment: How would you answer it if I were to ask you to explain why "In an inertial frame of reference, an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a force"?

Comment: *"But how this exactly take place?"* - are you asking for a non-mathematical explanation of the Lorentz force?

Comment: So we have a loernz force acting on the electrons.
Lets imagine a rod being orthogonally inserted into a magnetic field.
How does the lorenz force effect the electrons and the tip of the rod while being insert and then the ones that come in the next parts of the rhode ? how does this result in a current? or a voltage.

Comment: Also please yes an explination for the lorenzforce

Answer (score 0):

do you understand, that a moving charge is accelerated in a magnetic field? Seen from the magnetic field the charge is moving, so you have a force from the magnetic field. The direction of the force  depends on the direction of the movement,so the force reverses if the movement inverses.

Comment: This is the lorenz force. Yes i understand this effect